# How to ask a person who has just arrived about the road

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm wondering how to ask a person who has just arrived whether his commuting was fine. Could you say

> Was the road fine?

Comment: This appears to be a question about social norms than english usage.

Comment: @Eugene Did you have a good trip?

Comment: Around here it would be "How were the roads?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems to me like the phrase you're looking for is "How was your trip?" If you ask someone how the road was, generally they will assume you're asking whether it was well-maintained (i.e., were there [potholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pothole)), or, if there was bad weather, whether the road was slippery or icy.

Answer (score 3):

The usual inquiry in the NE US, where in most winters the road conditions may vary greatly, might be

> **How were the roads from (place)?**
>
> One might also say
>   **How was the drive (*also: driving*)?**

Colloquial usage may vary widely and colorfully, of course

Comment: What is the more general phrase?

Comment: @Eugene - Omit the point of origin. "How were the roads?" Asking "Was the driving fine?" would be appropriate only if one wished to sound like a non-native speaker groping for the approximate phrase.  (Native speakers will understand the question, and will probably be nice about it.)

Comment: And if someone just flied?